# Can someone fix all the broken links to the Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

Tags: support, status-completed, data-explorer, broken-link, link-rot

The URL for the Stack Exchange Data Explorer changed from `odata.stackexchange.com` to [`data.stackexchange.com`](http://data.stackexchange.com) some time ago.

[There are still a lot of broken links on Meta SO to the old Data Explorer URL](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A*odata.stackexchange.com*&submit=search). Can we get these updated?

Now when anybody goes to the old links all they see is:
[image: Screenshot of the page shown for hyperlinks to odata.stackexchange.com]

Comment: Nice. I saw one of these in a suggested edit a moment ago, but didn't realize how many of them were still lying around. I've [proposed fixing the error page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106709/fix-odata-error-page), by the way.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why the redirect isn't working anymore (although that's not to say the links shouldn't just be fixed anyway).

Answer (score 6):

The redirect is back up and working, give it a try: http://odata.stackexchange.com

SEDE was totally rebuilt with our Oregon web tier, and the old binding for odata.stackexchange.com simply didn't survive the move...it's just been corrected.