# Fix ODATA error page

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, data-explorer, 500-server-error

According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106705/can-someone-fix-all-the-broken-links-to-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer), the old http://odata.stackexchange.com URL is permanently disabled. Could someone change its error page to be more permanent? Right now, it's using the page with this text:

> ### This Stack Exchange site is currently offline for maintenance
>
> Routine maintenance usually takes less than an hour. If this turns into an extended outage, we will post details on [the blog](http://blog.serverfault.com/).

The outage is as extended as can be, and there are no details at that blog.

*Meta-note: I tried to tag this* [odata](/questions/tagged/odata)*, but it got automatically converted to* [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer) *because there's a synonym relationship.*

Comment: Duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106705/can-someone-fix-all-the-broken-links-to-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer (sort of)

Comment: You mean the question that I explicitly stated was the one that inspired this one? At the time I asked this, there was no screenshot at that one yet. It was a completely separate question. And the other one's intent remains different.

Comment: lol i did not notice that -- sorry.

Comment: Hmm, will look into this. (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kyle fixed this yesterday, we had a missing haproxy rule.